# Angular material styling is not drawing in browser

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material

The prebuilt Angular material theme is not working. I tried all the different ways to add CSS/SCSS to my new application:

- styles.scss `@import '~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css';`
- index.html `<link href="../node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css" rel="stylesheet">`
- `angular.json` adding under the styles section
- copying `indigo-pink.css` to `assets/` and point all above to it.

The problem is that actually the browser does see CSS file - it shows all CSS data, for every tag (e.g. mat-button),
but it does not draw it as it is shown in Angular docs.
Also noted that in dev mode in browser in style tab Angulars tags are shown but stroke through.

Here's how it looks like:
[the problem view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FRqxx.png)

Comment: Can you copy `angular.json` file here? How have you added it to the styles section?